# What does the GradleDaemon daemon do?

Tags: multithreading, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

In a machine I observe that `org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.1` is running running and having **lots** of threads.
It seems to be related to some build but I don't understand why it seems to stay alive with so many threads and if the settings of 
`-XX:MaxPermSize` `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` `-Xms1024m` `-Xmx2048` 
are programmer configured or picked up based on some detection

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Exactly what is your question? Perhaps you could edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jolta: I updated post. Is it better?

Comment: Is the question "why does Gradle use so many threads"?

Comment: @Jolta:I guess that would be the gist of it yes

Comment: I'd question back : why do you think it is a problem to have many threads? =) You could always ask on the gradle forums, the developers often answer design questions there.

Comment: @Jolta: having many threads may or may not be a problem. It depends on why they are needed and if they are actually doing anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

The title question and some of the additional ones are answered by the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) itself.

In short, the Gradle daemon enables using a hot JVM for running Gradle builds. And the parallel feature of Gradle means it uses a number of threads based on heuristics derived from the specification of the machine running it.

Comment: In the gradle code base at https://github.com/gradle/gradle - though I cannot point you to the specific location - exercise left to the curious reader :-)